# Pandas pct_change unsupported operand / for str and float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to execute the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('statistic.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], 
low_memory=False, nrows=5000000)
data_extracted = data.groupby(['DATE','ARTICLENO'])['QUANTITY'].sum().unstack()

data_extracted = data_extracted.loc['2015-01-01' : '2015-12-31']

data_extracted = data_extracted.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 
np.nan).fillna(0.0001)
data_pct_change = data_extracted.pct_change(axis=0).replace([np.inf, - 
np.inf], np.nan).fillna(0)
data_pct_change.drop([col for col, val in data_pct_change.sum() if val == 0 
], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

When i execute this, i get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'.
When i try to do `data_extracted['ARTICLENO] = data_extracted['ARTICLENO'].astype(float)` i get the same error.
When I print data_extracted.dtypes, it is all float.
Can someone help me?

Comment: I just see this answer, not working?

Comment: i did .astype(float).pct_change() ..., because your answer threw some errors:)

Answer (score 1):

I think need convert non numeric values to `NaN`s:

```
data_extracted['ARTICLENO'] = pd.to_numeric(data_extracted['ARTICLENO'], errors='coerce')
```